# PHP & PHPMailer : Can not send an attached file when fopen is disabled

Tags: php, curl, phpmailer

I have used PHPMailer for 10 years with no problems.
But, now my server need to disable "fopen" in PHP which is affected "file_get_contents" in PHPMailer.
I try CURL  instead of "file_get_contents".
Every thing is Okay, sending text, but an attach file cannot be sent.
This is my CURL that I use instead of "file_get_contents":

```
function file_get_contents_curl($url) {
  $ch = curl_init();
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, TRUE);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);       
  $data = curl_exec($ch);
  curl_close($ch);
  return $data;
}
```

I use PHPMailer 6.1.6.
The problem is in a PHPMailer.php, function encodeFile @ line 3143

```
$file_buffer = file_get_contents($path);
```

How do I send a file with out "file_get_contents";
Please help me, I try to fix this for a month.

Thank you in advance.
Na.

---

Here is error when I send a message:

30352#0: *9113244 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: PHP Fatal error: Uncaught PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception: File Error: Could not open file: temp/attachFile.jpg in /var/www/vhosts/kjubzz.com/php7v5.kjubzz.com/lib/PHPMailer/src/PHPMailer.php:3147
Stack trace:

#0 /var/www/vhosts/kjubzz.com/php7v5.kjubzz.com/lib/PHPMailer/src/PHPMailer.php(3115): PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer->encodeFile()

#1
/var/www/vhosts/kjubzz.com/php7v5.kjubzz.com/lib/PHPMailer/src/PHPMailer.php(2624): PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer->attachAll()

#2 /var/www/vhosts/kjubzz.com/php7v5.kjubzz.com/lib/PHPMailer/src/PHPMailer.php(1532): PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer->createBody()

#3 /var/www/vhosts/kjubzz.com/php7v5.kjubzz.com/lib/PHPMailer/src/PHPMailer.php(1430): PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer->preSend()

#4 /var/www/vhosts/kjubzz.com/php7v5.kjubzz.com/contact3.php(157): PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer->send()

#5 {main}
thrown in /var/www/vhosts/kjubzz.com/php7v5.kjubzz.com/lib/PHPMailer/src/PHPMailer.php on line 3147" while reading upstream

Comment: Can you tell us if you are getting an error from this code?

Answer (score 0):

I answered this [on Github](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/issues/2122#issuecomment-682821978).

My main recommendation here would be to switch to a hosting provider that provides a proper PHP config.

Failing that, you can retrieve files any way that you can (curl is fine), but if you can't read or write local files directly at all, it all needs to happen in memory, and PHPMailer provides the addStringAttachment() method to allow you to do just that, so you can follow your above code with:

$mail->addStringAttachment(file_get_contents_curl($url), 'myimage.jpg');
and it should all work out. Bear in mind though that you need to be a bit more careful than I suggest here - you need to do some error checking of the response in case the fetch fails before handing the result to PHPMailer.

Comment: Thank you so much Synchro,

I tried your code, but no luck.
$mail->addStringAttachment(file_get_contents_curl($url), 'myimage.jpg');
The message is sent (no error), text and file, but an attached files that show in Gmail cannot open.

The attached file in gmail show its name but 0 byte and cannot open (attachfile.jpg)


Please help me.